# Different behavior in VBA when in debug mode (steps) or in automatic mode

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel Macro which makes Hyperlinks in the first column of a table.

When i run it step by step in manual mode, it works fine and the hyperlinks are created.

When i run it in automatic mode, it runs without any error but the hyperlinks are not created.

I do not have any ideas why...?

```
Public Sub aktualisieren()

    Call Column_MakeHyperlinks(1)

End Sub
```

and then

```
    Sub Column_MakeHyperlinks(Blatt)

    ' ### Start Tabellenanalyse ###
    '   - Länge
    '   - Start
    '   - Ende

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WS = Sheets(Blatt) '
    Set Tabelle = WS.ListObjects(1) ' Get Table 

    Anzahl = Tabelle.ListRows.Count ' Number of Rows in Table
    Start = Tabelle.ListRows(1).Range.Row ' First Row in Table
    Ende = Tabelle.ListRows(Tabelle.ListRows.Count).Range.Row ' Last Row in Table

    sMsg = "There are " & Anzahl & " Rows in '" & Tabelle.Name & "'. "
    sMsg = sMsg & DNL & "Start in Row " & Start
    sMsg = sMsg & NL & ", Ende in Row " & Ende
    'MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation, UCase(sTableName) ' Activate for Text-Output

    ' ### Ende Tabellenanalyse ###

    iRow = Start ' Start at first Row with content
    iCol = 1 ' Column A

    ' Parameters, which should be concatenated to the link are in column A
    WS.Hyperlinks.Delete

    Do While WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> ""
        ' create Hyperlink (fixed prefix and dynamic parameter
        Temp = WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        'WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Select ' Not necessary, only to make active cell visible in manual mode
        WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Cells(iRow, iCol), Address:="https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value, _
        TextToDisplay:=Temp, _
        ScreenTip:="https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value

        'move to the next row
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

Can anyone explain me why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The issue is probably related to your use of `ActiveSheet`. Try replacing with `WS` that you've already use to determine the variable `Tabelle`.

Comment: i replaced "ActiveSheet" with "WS" but this unfortunately didn't fix my issue...

Comment: I changed it, but the issue is still left...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my problem: I got the Data in the first Column from a Database. When i do the refresh, it runs in the Background and the links are created while the data is still imported.

I found a checkbox "Allow Background actualization" in the "Connections" menu and unchecked it. This and the Answer of user avb solved my problem.

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

For me your code works, hyperlinks are created, but seem to be "inactive".
I added:

```
    WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
```

before iRow increment which solved the problem of hyperlinks "activity".
Also the way you iterate through cells of listobject's column should be rather like:

```
For Each c In Tabelle.ListColumns("column_name").DataBodyRange
    Temp = c.Value
    WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & c.Value, _
    TextToDisplay:=Temp, _
    ScreenTip:="https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & c.Value
    c.Value = c.Value
Next
```

Comment: i exactly implemented the code as you wrote it, but i still have the problem, that the hyperlinks are not activated. when i do the manual mode, and step with F8, everything works fine. :-(

Comment: HI ALL !!! i have a important informatuion. I get the Values in Column "A" from a Database:

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("V_DATA").Refresh

When i deactivate it, then the Hyperlinks are activated. When i activate it, it seems that the hyperlinks are created first, and then they are overwritten by the refresh, although the refresh is done first. So it seems that vba is not synchronized. Do i have to implement a "wait" or is there a way to make sure that the refresh is done until my VBA continues?